# LP2951 external transistor

Tags: power-supply, bjt, linear-regulator

I want to use LP2951 reference design from ONsemi datasheet (picture below). I'm not going to build the current limiting section of the schematic because the device will have external overvoltage/overcurrent protection. The remaining part of the circuit is quite straightforward, except of 0.33uF cap between PNP base and collector.

What is its purpose, how does it affect the behavior of the regulator and how can I properly calculate its value for specific conditions, for example certain input and output voltages, or different model of a PNP transistor (D45H11 for example)?

UPD: As far as I understand this cap is added to maintain stability of the regulator, but in exchange of reducing its PSRR at higher frequencies. So I need the lowest value possible with which  system stays stable. So once more: how can I calculate this value, or under what conditions do I need to test the regulator while choosing the suitable value on practice?

[image: Figure 26 from OnSemi LP2951 datasheet]

(Image source: [OnSemi LP2951 datasheet, Figure 26](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/lp2950-d.pdf))